# While creating framework from project facing (Cocoa Pods) file missing issue

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, dynamic-linking

I have sample project which is using Cocoa Pods. Now I wanted to create a iOS framework on top of that project. I am getting error for file missing as project used some cocoa pods files? How should I resolve this?

Comment: What error? What "some files"?

Comment: I am using ReverseAuth sample code for twitter login in which OAuthCore/OAuthCore.h file is missing. https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample/tree/master/Source/Classes

Answer (score 0):

I have got the other way work around, I extracted the missing files from the Pods group in project (sample one) and added in my project. So it's working now.